# Unable to connect to SSH on my laptop

Tags: ssh, 13.10

I installed SSH server and client using the commands in Ubuntu 13.10

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

But then I am able to connect using my client to any other ssh server on the network by

```
ssh username@hostname
```

But when I try connecting ssh-client on my laptop to itself. It says permission denied, Please try again.

```
$ : ssh shubhang@10.109.59.55
shubhang@10.109.59.55's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Does it work if you try `ssh shubhang@localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

1. make sure you have the following `PasswordAuthentication yes # Default anyway`
2. make sure the users is not in `DenyUsers` and `DenyGroups`.

This cloud be cause by various reasons (misconfiguration or permissions), the best way is to start both sshd and ssh client in verbose mode.

For example:

#### sshd

Stop sshd and then run `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd`

#### Client

Connect => `ssh user@host -vvv`

Look at the debug output and it'll point you to the root cause, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ssh try installing openssh,  it always works for me.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer on how to do that? You can [edit] your answer by clicking the edit link right underneath the text of your answer. Thanks!